# Mail the contents of a log file in perl

Tags: html, perl, email, sendmail, mime

i want to mail the contents of a log file of another script  . I have tried the code it works , but however the output is not i expected. I want the output in line by line exactly like in LOG.txt, but i get it in as a paragraph in the body.

```
my $HOME        ='/apps/stephen/data';
my $FILE        ="$HOME/LOG.txt";
my @HTML        =();

sub copyfile
{
 `$HOME/APPL.ksh > $FILE`;

  push(@HTML,`cat $FILE`);

&sendMail;
}

sub sendMail
{
$sub="TEST";
$from='ABC@ABC.com';
$to='ABC@ABC.com';
    open(MAIL, "|/usr/lib/sendmail -t");
            print MAIL "From: $from \12"; print MAIL "To: $to \12";print    MAIL "Cc: $Cc \12";
            print MAIL "Subject: $sub \12";
            print MAIL "Content-Type: text/html \12";
            print MAIL "Content-Disposition:inline \12";
            print MAIL @HTML;
    close(MAIL);
}

sub init
{
    copyfile;

}
init;
```

Comment: I'd also recommend using [MIME::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite) rather than manually calling sendmail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add missing `MIME-Version:` header to complete `Content-*:` headers.

```
open(MAIL, "|/usr/lib/sendmail -i -t");
print MAIL << "END";
From: $from
To: $to
Cc: $Cc
Subject: $sub
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: inline

END
print MAIL @HTML;
close(MAIL)
```

;